# Drawing a sprite Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I am trying to draw a sprite using the libgdx wiki as bases for an exampel: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-Textureregions%2C-and-Sprites
But i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.MKgames.OptionScreen.render(OptionScreen.java:44)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

what is the best way to draw a sprite for a 2d game, what is best practice???

Here is my Option screen class including the render method:

```
    package com.MKgames;

import sun.java2d.loops.DrawGlyphListAA.General;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class OptionScreen implements Screen{

    com.MKgames.Game1 game;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;


    int farmerX;

    public OptionScreen(com.MKgames.Game1 game1){
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        farmerX = 960-85;

    }


    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        camera.update();
        generalUpdate();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
            FarmerAsset.farmer1.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

    }


    public void generalUpdate() {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)||Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
            farmerX -= 5;
        }
        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)||Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
            farmerX += 5;   
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

}
```

And a class FarmerAsset to hold the farmer Sprite:
package com.MKgames;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;

public class FarmerAsset {

    public static Texture texture_sheet;
    public static Sprite farmer1;
    public static Sprite farmer2;
    public static Sprite farmer3;
    public static Sprite farmer4;
    public static Sprite farmer5;
    public static Sprite farmer6;
    public static Sprite farmer7;
    public static Sprite farmer8;

    public static void load(){
        texture_sheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("farmerSprite.png"));
        farmer1 = new Sprite (texture_sheet, 0, 0, 170, 170);
        farmer2 = new Sprite (texture_sheet, 170, 0, 170, 170);
        farmer3 = new Sprite (texture_sheet, 340, 0, 170, 170);
        farmer4 = new Sprite (texture_sheet, 680, 0, 170, 170);
        farmer5 = new Sprite (texture_sheet, 0, 170, 170, 170);
        farmer6 = new Sprite (texture_sheet, 170, 170, 170, 170);
        farmer7= new Sprite (texture_sheet, 340, 170, 170, 170);
        farmer8= new Sprite (texture_sheet, 680, 170, 170, 170);
        farmer1.flip(false, true);
        farmer2.flip(false, true);
        farmer3.flip(false, true);
        farmer4.flip(false, true);
        farmer5.flip(false, true);
        farmer6.flip(false, true);
        farmer7.flip(false, true);
        farmer8.flip(false, true);
        }


}
```

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but your sprites may have not loaded. What is actually null on that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a NPE because you didn't instantiate your sprite before trying to render it. In your init() method of your screen (I guess you have one, as render(float) is in it and you're using it), call `FarmerAsset.load();`. This will load your texture just like you asked it.

[EDIT] After looking at your crash log, I see you might be using a Game instead of a Screen. Don't get confused, it's pretty much the same thing as Game implements Screen.

```
public OptionScreen(com.MKgames.Game1 game1){
    this.game = game;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    farmerX = 960-85;

    //This is what's missing
    FarmerAsset.load();

}
```

Comment: pls see my new edit and  could u expand on your edit, sorry im very new to libgdx and java in general :) thank u